# Safety of generating a threaddump on a production system

Tags: jvm

We have a production Java system which is using a lot more threads than usual. I would like to use `kill -3  pid` to get a threaddump, and if necessary get a binary heap dump using JConsole for offline analysis in Eclipse MAT.

I am running Java 1.5.0_10 on RHEL4.

How likely is it that either of these will kill the JVM? What about adverse effects on its performance while the dumps are produced?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It won't kill the VM, but generating a heap dump will likely freeze the JVM during the dump process, since it has to dump a consistent snapshot. Once the dump has finished, it'll resume all threads from where they were suspended. So it won't be destructive, but it'll briefly stop processing.

Comment: I assume the thread dump is a lot less expensive to produce than the Heap Dump. Does it even need to pause the VM?

Comment: @Rich: Much less expensive, yes. It'll still have to pause the VM, but it'll take so little time you won't notice it.

Answer (score -4):

I use below command to get heap  dump

jmap -heap pid

For details - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't answer the question